# Every time I'm trying to install the php-mysqli extension I'm getting error like "E: Package 'php-mysqli' has no installation candidate"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-extension

```
suvo@Suvodip-Lenovo ~ $ sudo apt install php-mysqli

[sudo] password for suvo:

Reading package lists... Done`enter code here`

Building dependency tree    

Reading state information... Done

Package php-mysqli is a virtual package provided by:

php7.3-mysql 7.3.2-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

php7.2-mysql 7.2.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

php7.1-mysql 7.1.26-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

php5.6-mysql 5.6.40-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

php7.0-mysql 7.0.33-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package `php-mysqli` has no installation candidate
```

Comment: The message is very clear: *"You should explicitly select one to install."* Install the most recent one - 7.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Understand the error message

> Package php-mysqli is a virtual package provided by:
>   [...]

The `apt` package management uses virtual packages to fulfill dependencies. A virtual package itself has no content at all. It cannot be installed directly. It is meant as an indicator that the expected software was installed to signal other packages that their dependencies are resolved.

`apt` tells you a list of real packages which install the virtual one. Just install the most recent one (or, if you alread have installed another PHP version, the matching version):

```
sudo apt install php7.3-mysql
```

Comment: I have tried this sudo apt install php8.2-mysql and I got this reply php8.2-mysql is already the newest version (8.2.5-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).  but still getting same error

Comment: @NarenVerma That means, `php8.2-mysql` is already installed.  You should find `mysqli.ini` in /etc/php/8.2/mods-available. You might need a `sudo phpenmod mysqli` to enable it. Remember to restart Apache.

Comment: Tried but still same issue.

Comment: @user9437856 you should open a new question and describe, what your issue exactly is.